# Encrypted config kubernetes on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I recently saw [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/) on the ability to encrypt secrets at rest. I am currently running kubernetes on Google Cloud, but I can't figure out how to set it up with the kube-apiserver. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the article, there is an important note where you have to properly restrict permissions on the Master nodes for this to work correctly. At this time, the Master node is not accessible by customers as it is a managed service within GKE.

The only suggestion I can offer at this time if you would like to implement this feature is to [create a Cluster from scratch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch/) within GCE. This way you will have full control of the cluster, including being able to make changes to the Master node.